# can too much antifreeze cause a p1281 code

Tags: coolant, jeep, liberty

2002 Jeep Liberty I added coolant to top off reservoir now I have a p 1281 code . Do I need to drain coolants and start over

Answer (score 1):

No. A P1281 code means the engine isn't reaching operating temp in the amount of time the ECM expects. Usually a bad thermostat.

Comment: That's not the code he reported - are they the same?

Comment: The heater was blowing out cold air also . I will replace thermostat and report back thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I misread the code and thot he said P0128. P1281 is "Engine is cold too long," so it's close to P0128. The P1281 code sets if the engine coolant doesn't reach 181°F while driving for more than 3 minutes.